# Filter all requests for certain entities?

Tags: typeorm

There are certain cases where it would be very advantageous to be able to annotate all queries for a certain entity (or maybe all queries in the app) with certain conditions. E. g. when I use a `USER` model and I want queries like `findOne` and `find` to not return the password and salt for `user` instances. I don't want to delete the properties from every query - instead, I want to do this only once.

Another use case would be to filter for a specific tenant in my application.

As of now, I haven't seen this functionality with TypeORM. Does it exist?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `select: false` to a column in an entity and this will take you the ability to not select this column by default.

For example:

```
@Entity('user')
export class USER {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', default: null, select: false }) <-- here
  salt: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255, default: null, select: false }) // <-- here
  password: string;
}
```

---

But in cases when you forced to select these columns you could use `QueryBuilder` for this entity and `addSelect()` these columns:

```
this.userRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .where({ firstName: 'John' })
  .addSelect(['user.salt', 'user.password'])
  .getOne();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I get that it was somewhat misleading. I was particularly interested in the option to add an additional filter to all query methods as described above. Your solution works for the user example (thanks for that) but can't be applied to force all queries of a entity to include a `WHERE` condition for a  tenant.